# Why is the CPU frequency stuck at half the maximum tolerance?

Tags: cpu, frequency, governor

I have an old Processor Intel® Core™2 CPU T7200 @ 2.00GHz × 2
Why is the current frequency stuck at 1GHZ if the CPU is built for up to 2GHZ?

Here are the frequency #s when I run the following script

```
root@imparoUbuntu-ThinkPad-T60:~#  paste <(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq) <(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq) <(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq) | column -s $'\t' -t
1000000  1000000  2000000

Min          Current        Max

1000000      1000000       2000000 

1000000      1000000       2000000
```

Also please see "current policy" below:

```
$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1000 MHz - 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.00 GHz, 1.67 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1000 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  **current policy: frequency should be within 1000 MHz and 1000 MHz.**
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.00 GHz:100.00%, 1.67 GHz:0.00%, 1.33 GHz:0.00%, 1000 MHz:0.00%  (4)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1000 MHz - 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.00 GHz, 1.67 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1000 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  **current policy: frequency should be within 1000 MHz and 1000 MHz.**
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.00 GHz:100.00%, 1.67 GHz:0.00%, 1.33 GHz:0.00%, 1000 MHz:0.00%  (5)
```

PS: I already changed governor to "performance" but current policy keeps frequency range at 1000 MHZ for both min and max despite the CPU being built for 2Ghz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the pros and cons of CPU frequency control on a laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141218/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-cpu-frequency-control-on-a-laptop)  Overclocking is only as safe as you know what you're doing. You can definitely fry your parts if you mess up, especially if you alter voltages.  It's usually not worth the risk to get a few extra hundred Mhz clock speeds, unless you're frequently running tasks that need 100% of your CPU for a long period of time

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 bit.

Comment: If trying this would also keep an eye on temperatures.

Comment: @Nmath you are right, I'll end up frying this thing. I am just curious to what the limits are. I must say for being dead a week ago, the T60 is doing great for my needs. So probably best not to tinker any further. it already runs pretty warm at my touch all the time. Perhaps a script to keep the temp in check is more in order... if such a thing exists. Thank you both for taking the time. I added further details in the body of the main question.

Comment: Well that's the thing about overclocking - there is no defined limit. This is due to the fabrication process of silicon - even among the same model CPUs will have slight differences that affect the ability to OC. If you have a laptop, do not overclock - remember that there is other hardware crammed into that tiny chassis and excess heat can damage parts and melt plastics

Comment: Laptops are generally designed to operate up to thermal max anyway

Comment: Quite a few temp sensors available in CLI and GUI for Ubuntu/Linux.  Had an older AMD CPU and usually had to keep it at low power because it would go past 80 easily often if not.

Comment: @Nmath  After a few days I discovered what kept the "policy" stuck at 1Ghz well below2Ghz. I was using the laptop without the battery.  It turns out when you take off the battery the machine is built to halve CPU frequency.  Once I put the battery back on frequency was back at full range up to 2Ghz. Thanks to this link. http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_CPU_frequency_scaling    I thought I put this out there as it might save a lot of headaches to others incurring in the same problem.